# Tables in IE7 displaying inline

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have two tables in ie7 inside a div. The div has a width property set to 500px. The tables are inside the div and have (each) a width property set to 450px.

When the page is rendered in IE7, the second table displays next to the first table (same line) even though the parent div has a width of 500px, which is not being respected.

This displays ok in all other browsers.

How can I tell IE7 to display the second table below the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Create a small hack in CSS targeting only IE7.

For Your Reference [IE Only CSS](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: +1 for the reference, but I'm trying to avoid adding a conditional ie specific css file

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround ...

```
1) Put a <br/> tag after the first table. This will always display 2nd table below the 1st one.

2) Add <div style="clear:both"> </div> after the first table. This will do the same as above.
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieving cross browser compatibility in you case, you can **html5shiv.js** which you will find [here](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/zipball/master). I have used it in most of my projects for cross browser compatibility. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I"m not sure this changes how tables behave in ie7, but I'll give it a try and update.

Comment: The "html5" in html5shiv means it's for compatibility with new HTML5 elements (article, section, etc). Table isn't an HTML5 element that wouldn't be recognized by IE8- ...